# Is it safe to swap an instance of map with a temporary map?

Tags: c++, stl

```
    using std::map;
    map<string, int> mapStrToInt;
    {
            map<string, int> mapStrToInt2;
            mapStrToInt2[ "h1" ] = 100;
            mapStrToInt2[ "h2" ] = 200;
            mapStrToInt2[ "h3" ] = 300;
            mapStrToInt2[ "h4" ] = 400;

            mapStrToInt.insert( mapStrToInt2.begin( ), mapStrToInt2.end( ) );
            mapStrToInt.swap( mapStrToInt2 ); // is this code safe?
    }
    // at this point mapStrToInt2 has been destroyed.
```

**Question**> I have tested this code with VS2013 and the content of `mapStrToInt` has been swapped with that of `mapStrToInt2`. However, I still want to confirm that swapping the content of a temporary object is safe & legal.

Thank you

Comment: the code as it stands is perfectly legal..

Answer (score 4):

It is both safe and legal. When swapping the contents of two containers, the ownership of the contents changes from one to the other. So the old contents of `mapStrToInt` are owned by the temporary and cease to exist when exiting the scope, while the old contents of the temporary are taken over by `mapStrToInt`.